# Is there a template for a website that accepts an uploaded file, does something, and lets the user download the result?

Tags: ruby, web-applications, file-upload, twitter-bootstrap

I have a few Ruby scripts that process text files in different ways, that many of my friends find useful. However, most of the people I know are not comfortable running scripts on the command line. The easiest thing for them would be to create a simple webpage where people could upload a file, select a few options, have it processed, and then download the result.

I know it wouldn't be too hard to build something like this in Rails or Merb or something like that, however it seems like a very common problem, so I was wondering if there was already some kind of template, or similar application that I could easily modify, i.e. let the user upload a file, choose a few options, then {fill in code to do something with file}, let the user download the resulting file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [sinatra-fileupload](https://github.com/tbuehlmann/sinatra-fileupload), which pretty perfectly answers my question. It's a very minimalistic framework which works perfectly, I can just plug in the file handling, and change the layout etc a bit. There were many examples of sophisticated Rails plugins linked to databases, with versioning and stuff, but I really wanted the most minimal example.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I used Carrierwave to upload user avatars.
If you are used to Rails it's really straightforward.

Let it be a TextFile resource:

```
gem 'carrierwave'

$ rails g scaffold textfile content:string title:string etc etc
$ rails g uploader textfile

class TextFile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accesible :content
  mount_uploader :content, TextFileUploader
end
```

And that is is pretty much all you have to do to obtain the app's skeleton. However, to answer your real question, no, I don't think there is already a rails app that does *exactly* that. 
https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave